# User self relationship hasMany (parent/children) return null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many

I have **User** model with `parent_id` column, and have relationship defined as follow:

```
public function superior()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'superior_id', 'id');
}

public function subordinates()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'superior_id', 'id');
}
```

I have test data setup like this:

```
user1

    user2

        user5

    user3

user4
```

(meaning user2 has `parent_id` = 1, user5 has `parent_id` = 2)

when I call `$user2->superior` it works (return $user1). However I call `$user2->subordinates` it return null (should be a collection contains `user5`).

I tried to iterate but the result doesn't change.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, but can you try something like `Model::subordinates()->toSql();` and see if that prints an SQL so we check what it is doing ? Also, if it does not work, just add a `where` between `subordinates()` and `toSql()` so you can really use it.

Comment: @matiaslauriti
It return 

"select * from `users` where `users`.`superior_id` = ? and `users`.`superior_id` is not null"

I'm not sure how it has condition 'is not null' and how to get rid of it.

Edit: it seem "`users`.`superior_id` is not null" does not affect the logic and is not the reason (?)

Comment: yeah, `is not null` it is because it is a relation, you never get `null` results (at least for `collections`). Are you sure `user5` has `superior_id` = `user2->id` ? Check your DB please and also run the same query it returned but where you see the `?` write the `user2->id` and check if it returns `user5`. (run that query manually in MySQL server please)

Comment: Yes, it return 2. I posted the result here: https://pastebin.com/5pgJieUm

Comment: but, if you run that query replacing `?` with the correct ID, run it in MySQL, do you get something back ?

Comment: @matiaslaurit My bad. It's because I set $this->user5->superior_id = $this->user2->id BUT didn't persist it ($this->user5->save()).

Answer (score 0):

My bad. It's because I set $this->user5->superior_id = $this->user2->id BUT didn't persist it ($this->user5->save()).

I can find the issue after doing what @matiaslaurit adviced:
check
`Model::subordinates()->toSql();` and `Check your DB please and also run the same query it returned`